# Nuxt Server Side Rendering app good SEO with Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I created a very SEO-friendly Nuxt SSR app, and I'd like to deploy it on Google Firebase's Cloud Functions.

Does anyone know how effectively it's going to be indexed?
Maybe the serverless nature of Cloud Functions is not going to be excellent for SEO?
Or maybe some extra script in the cloud function code could help even better?

Any tip or comment would be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions as no bearing on any sort of SEO.  It's just a serverless compute product.  The only thing that matters for SEO is your actual content.  The product you use the deploy it has no effect, as long as the content is reachable.  If you want your content to do well in search results, you should use the tools provided by the search result vendor (for example, Google Search) to manage indexing.

Comment: Thank you very much Doug, appreciated.

What about Cloud Functions' cold start? 
Could it affect how fast my landing page will load when the traffic is not very high, with possible consequences in how the crawlers "judge" my website?

Comment: Doubtful that it would have much effect, if any.  I suggest consulting the documentation on Google Search (or whatever search product you're using) to understand what effect latency has on search ranking, then measure that yourself.